# joining arrays in Matlab and writing to file using dlmwrite( ) adds extra space

Tags: matlab

I am generating 2500 values in Matlab in format (time,heart_rate, resp_rate) by using below code

```
 numberOfSeconds = 2500;
 time = 1:numberOfSeconds;
 newTime = transpose(time);
 number0 = size(newTime, 1)


 %   generating heart rates 
heart_rate = 50 +(70-50) * rand (numberOfSeconds,1);
intHeartRate = int64(heart_rate);
number1 = size(intHeartRate, 1)
% hist(heart_rate)


 %   generating resp rates 
resp_rate = 50 +(70-50) * rand (numberOfSeconds,1);
intRespRate = int64(resp_rate);
number2 = size(intRespRate, 1)
% hist(heart_rate)


% joining time and sensor data
 joinedStream = strcat(num2str(newTime),{','},num2str(intHeartRate),{','},num2str(intRespRate))

 dlmwrite('/Users/amar/Desktop/geenrated/rate.txt', joinedStream,'delimiter','');
```

The data shown in the console is alright, but when I save this data to a .txt file, it contains extra spaces in beginning. Hence I am not able to parse the .txt file to generate input stream. Please help

Comment: The data written in the file is exactly what is shown in the *console*.  See what the first element of `joinedStream` i.e.  `joinedStream(1)`  is

Comment: Are you interested in knowing why extra space is added? I can post that as answer if you're interested

Comment: Yes sure , please

Answer (score 2):

Replace the last two lines of your code with the following. No need to use strcat if you want a CSV output file.

```
dlmwrite('/Users/amar/Desktop/geenrated/rate.txt', [newTime intHeartRate intRespRate]);
```

Answer (score 2):

[ℎ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46032181/5698672)      ℎ    . ℎ   ℎ   ℎ  .

---

The data written in the file is exactly what is shown in the console.

```
>> joinedStream(1)   %The exact output will differ since 'rand' is used

ans =
  cell

    '   1,60,63'
```

[`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) basically converts a matrix into a character array. Hence number of characters in its each row must be same. So for each column of the original matrix, the row with the maximum number of characters is set as a standard for all the rows with less characters and the deficiency is filled by spaces. Columns are separated by 2 spaces. Take a look at the following smaller example to understand:

```
>> num2str([44, 42314; 4, 1212421])

ans =
  2×11 char array

    '44    42314'
    ' 4  1212421'
```